# Detecting the source link or button use to navigate to a new webpage

Tags: php, html

There is a button and a link on a webpage, and both go to the same next page. When a user lands on the next page, I want to know whether they had clicked on the button or the link on the previous page.

How can I get that information in the php for the landing page?

Comment: `$_GET` and `$_POST` superglobals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

Add some extra parameter to the link and the button.

For the link:

```
<a href="page.php?param1=1&param2=2&source=link">link text</a>
```

For the button:

```
<form ...>
<input type="hidden" name="source" value="button">
...
<input type="button" ...>
</form>
```

When processing the page inputs, check the `$_REQUEST['source']`

Comment: Was the answer satisfactory?